# Nested bootstrap rows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, nested, rows

I am testing a nested bootstrap rows within `col-md-`.  I have the following code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <header class="row-fluid clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-1 logo">  
      <img src="images/logo.png" width="100%">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-11 side">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-..
          <p>Test1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class=col-...
          <p>menu</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

In the above code, logo.png is a tall image, and I would like to have two rows on the column next to the column where the logo.png is. On the said two rows, the top one will have a small banner, and lower one will have a navbar.  I would like to align the top banner with the top edge of the logo.png, and navbar aligned to the lower edge of logo.png.

Could somebody on the forum suggest I could achieve this result?  I would not like to give a fixed height for the columns or the logo.png.

Thanks,
Maadis

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Bootstrap did you use? I am not sure there's a row-fluid class on the version 3.

However if row-fluid works for you, Try this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <header class="row-fluid">
   <div class="col-md-1 logo">  
     <img src="images/logo.png" width="100%">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-11 side">
     <div class="row-fluid">
       <div class="col-md-12">
         <p>Test1</p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-12">
         <p>menu</p>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </header>
</div>
```

Comment: I am using Bootstrap 3. I was unaware of row-fluid on bootstrap 3.  I will check further. Thanks for your comments -truly appreciated. Maadis